# Grails - how to connect to another database during an action

Tags: grails, datasource

What I need to do is this (either in an action or a service):

```
someAction() {
    // connect to database
    def otherDatasource = new Datasource(otherOptions)

    if (otherDatasource.isOnline()) {
        def list = ExclusiveDomainFromOtherDatasource.list()

        // do stuff with the data...

        otherDatasource.close()
    }
}
```

I'm not using datasources plugin because the other database may be offline and the app connects during first-run, or maybe I'm forgetting something.

I know I could use some basic jdbc library and make a raw sql for getting the data, but that isn't very groovish, is this the only way? or is there a plugin that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using some sort of custom DataSource, there is no isOnline() method, so you might as well just use the DataSources plugin.

Actually, newer versions of grails have multiple-datasource support built-in, so you don't need the plugin.

I think that you're just going to have to try to get a connection from the DataSource, and be prepared to catch and handle the exception that you'll get if the database is offline.

A well-configured database conneciton pool should allow you to start connecting successfully once the database comes online.